# Animation resetting view state?

Tags: android

i am trying to do some simple animation, i have list with items, those items include  also checkboxes
 on a checkbox button click i want to show with animation some button from the buttom, something like this:

private int mPosition;
        private CheckBox chkBox;

```
    OnItemClickListener(CheckBox mChkBox, View v)
    {

        chkBox = mChkBox;
        chkBox.setClickable(false);
        chkBox.setChecked(false);
        chkBox.setClickable(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (chkBox.isChecked())
                        {

                                  animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                R.layout.animation_slide_in);
                animation.setDuration(500);
                animation.setInterpolator(new  AccelerateInterpolator());
                btDeleteItms.startAnimation(animation);
                btDeleteItms.setVisibility(btDeleteItms.VISIBLE);

                        }
```

now the wierd thing, that after i click the checkboxbutton, the animation does work fine,but the state of the triggering checkbox button, is being uncheck unexpectdly?
how come? does animation resetting states somehow?

Thaks,

ray.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly you need to use animation.setFillAfter(true); after .startAnimation(animation) method.